# Adding element to array in function, but array is still empty

Tags: arrays, function, powershell, powershell-2.0

I'm sure it's a silly problem but I can't seem to add element to array in function.

PowerShell 2.0

```
$jobResult = @()

function Gather-JobResults {
    Param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
        [string] $message
    )
    begin {}
    process {
        $jobResult += ([string]::Format("{0} - {1}", (Get-Date -f "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"), $message))
        Write-Host "--- Status jobResult ---> $jobResult"
    }
    end{}
}

Gather-JobResults("zabaaa")
Gather-JobResults("zaaaauuuuuuuul")
Gather-JobResults("winkoooo")

$jobResult
```

The `$jobResult` is empty after I call 3x `Gather-JobResults`, how can I fix this ?

Thanks for any answers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this is a scope problem, when you modify $jobResult in your function , you're not modifying the global variable defined outside this function.

inside your function use `$global:jobResult += ...` (or $script:jobResult) and it should be ok

look at the [About_scope help page](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847849.aspx)